# datagridview cell click event

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I have an event for a cell click in a datagrid view to display the data in the clicked cell in a message box. I have it set to where it only works for a certain column and only if there is data in the cell

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3))
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

however, whenever i click any of the column headers, a blank messagebox shows up. I cant figure out why, any tips?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will also need to check the cell clicked is not the column header cell. Like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3) && e.RowIndex != -1){
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());   
}
```

Comment: Just notice that you should check ` dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null ` before the first condition ...

Answer (score 2):

Check that `CurrentCell.RowIndex` isn't the header row index.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.RowIndex == -1) return; //check if row index is not selected
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3))
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution throws an "object not set to an instance of an object" exception as null reference checking MUST happen before checking the actual value of a variable.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{    
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null ||
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == null ||
        e.RowIndex == -1) return;
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3))
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3)
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(0))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                 enter code here
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).