# How to enter DataGridView cell programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# `windows forms`. 
Using a `Button event` I want to programmatically enter the Cell of the `DataGridView` without a need to click on the cell using the mouse, I want to enter the "Main Price" cell of the selected row as shown in the screenshot.

```
  private void buttonEnterMainPriceCell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Enter Cell Main Price of the selected row
    }
```

I had a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592865/how-do-i-click-on-a-cell-of-a-datagridview-programmatically) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762036/datagridview-cell-click-event) and I tried the answers but it did not work. Also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719259/how-to-add-a-cell-programmatically-to-a-datagridview) is not what I want because I want to edit the cell and that one wants to add cell

Anyone knows how to do it?

[image]

Comment: You need to put it in edit mode - have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814423/datagridview-how-to-set-a-cell-in-editing-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Cell programmatically to a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719259/how-to-add-a-cell-programmatically-to-a-datagridview)

Comment: @Kevin it is already in edit mode.

Comment: @ styx this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please try my asnwer below...

Comment: Can you explain "Did not work"?

Comment: @ roozbeh S it did not work = the required cell does not get edited / entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this (you may have to change the cell number)

```
private void buttonEnterMainPriceCell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // Enter Cell Main Price of the selected row
       DataGridViewCell cell = DataGridView1.Rows[datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[3];
       dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
       dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```